# Automatic Firebase SDK not working: net::ERR_ABORTED 404

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase

Today is my first time deploying my Firebase app to the **production server**. All the while, it was working fine on my local machine on Firebase emulators. When loading my app from production server for the first time, I hit this error on the browser console:

```
GET https://my-project-id.web.app/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-auth.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
GET https://my-project-id.web.app/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-functions.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404
Uncaught TypeError: firebase.auth is not a function
    at index.js:19
    at index.js:72
```

#### Below is my `index.html`:

```
  <!-- update the version number as needed -->
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-app.js"></script>
  <!-- include only the Firebase features as you need -->
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
  <!-- <script defer src="/__/firebase/7.15.4/firebase-database.js"></script> -->
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-messaging.js"></script>
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-storage.js"></script>
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/8.0.1/firebase-functions.js"></script>
  <!-- initialize the SDK after all desired features are loaded -->
  <!-- <script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js?useEmulator=true"></script> -->
  <script defer src="/__/firebase/init.js"></script>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

  <script defer src="/scripts/index.js"></script>
```

Apparently, the `TypeError` was actually due to the loading failure of the SDKs, but I couldn't figure out the reason as the reserved SDK URLs seems to be correct according to the [Firebase Docs here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/reserved-urls). What else could it be wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

### Hours later, the error disappears...

**Potential Cause:**

1. The removal of `/__/firebase/init.js?useEmulator=true` has not yet taken effect after the deployment.
2. The Firebase re-deployment has not yet cleared the CDN cache, perhaps not immediate.

But the `net::ERR_ABORTED 404` error came before the `init.js`, I'm not sure if it was truly caused by the `useEmulator=true` URL parameter. Any other better answers are welcome. Thank you!